# How to block yum from upgrading obsoleted package?

Tags: yum, upgrade

Is there any way to prevent yum from upgrading a package obsoleted by another?

I have created a custom repo containing some packages, among them **`openh323-devel`**. In current versions of CentOS, **`openh323`** is marked as being obsoleted by OPAL, but I don't want to compile other software (namely YATE) against OPAL. I have **`openh323-devel`** installed, but every time I do `yum update`, it wants me to upgrade it to OPAL.

Is there any way I can tell **`yum`** that I permanently don't want to use OPAL (or any other superseding package for that matter) in a manner similar to apt pinning? Of course, I can `--exclude` specific packages, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to permanently add an exclude rule by adding it to your `/etc/yum.conf` file. You can also use wildcards to exclude more than one package based on a pattern. Try:

```
exclude=*OPAL*
```

Comment: OK, thanks, but that's what I'm doing at the moment. What I was thinking about was some method to prevent yum from upgrading any obsoleted packages. Probably I'll just stay with this method.

Comment: If you don't want to upgrade ANYTHING why are you running yum at all?

Comment: Heh, I still want to update all other system packages (for security, patches, etc.), I just don't want yum to mess with my custom package. What makes it funnier is that if I put newer version of openh323 to my repo, yum still prefers opal over it. Apparently, excluding is a way to go here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 13):

```
sudo yum --setopt=obsoletes=0 install obsoleted-package
```

Or you can put

```
obsoletes=0
```

to

```
/etc/yum.conf
```

Both ways worked for me on Oracle Linux 6.7.